# Vim operation - creating a new text object selector for entire file

Tags: key-bindings, visual-mode, custom-text-object

You can do `dap`, or `vap`, etc to select a paragraph. I want to be able to select/yank/delete the entire file.

One way to do this would be to have:

```
vnoremap af ggoG$
nnoremap yaf ggVGy
nnoremap daf ggVGd
```

But is there a way to create a new 'text object selector; (like `p` for paragraph, `w` for word, etc`) but with`f` for 'file? E.g. with omap?

Comment: Are you saying you would like to be able to select the entire file, then yank it and then delete it all in one go?

Comment: Not exactly. i would like to perform either of those mappings above with a single mapping. For example, the `ap` in `vap` or `dap` selects current paragraph - I would like to effectively create a new 'text object selector' (or whatever you would call the `p` in `vap`). I have reworded the title to hopefully be cleaer

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Creating_new_text_objects

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Wow exactly what I was looking for! You can make an answer if you like. And maybe copy in this: `omap af :normal Vaf<CR>
vnoremap af ggoG$`

Comment: Ah right yeah that makes a little more sense haha. Fyi ggyG and ggdG are equivalent to ggVGy and ggVGd respectively (gotta save all them excess chars). There's also some cool stuff with using specific registers so you are yanking/deleting with a bit more control. And you can even do it to clipboard so you're basically just copying/cutting